# What does overflow:hidden do besides hiding a scroll?

Tags: html, css

What does overflow:hidden do besides hiding a scroll? I fixed one issue just by an accident adding `overflow:hidden`. I thought it just makes scroll invisible. What else does it do? I couldn't find any good explanation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An `overflow` property not set to `visible` [creates a new block formatting context](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#block-formatting):

> Floats, absolutely positioned elements, block containers (such as inline-blocks, table-cells, and table-captions) that are not block boxes, and block boxes with 'overflow' other than 'visible' (except when that value has been propagated to the viewport) establish new block formatting contexts for their contents.

Answer (score 1):

in layman's terms it hides the clipped (parts that extend beyond the rectangle of the div that has its visibility set) so that the contents of the div that extend beyond the boundaries of the parent rectangle, are not visible (and not scrollable to).

Conversely `visible` will render those parts even when they are wider/taller than the parent and `auto` will hide them but allow access to them via a scrollbar.

So, if you have a parent div which is 100px x 100px and you start putting content in that div, the moment that content extends beyond the 100px boundary those parts stop being visible. It is possible to force scroll to them using javascript, depending on the browser, even if the visibility is set to hidden.

Answer (score 0):

> The overflow CSS property specifies whether to clip content, render scroll bars or display overflow content of a block-level element.

[docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/overflow)